# why in clojure (eval (list + 1 2)) and (eval (list '+ 1 2)) do the same thing?

Tags: clojure, quote

```
user=> (eval '(+ 1 2))
3
user=> (eval '('+ 1 2))
2
user=> (eval (list '+ '1 '2))
3
user=> (eval (list + '1 '2))
3
```

Did that mean '+ is sometimes the same from + ?

Is there any rule to determine what situation should be considered?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(list '+ '1 '2)` produces a list of the symbol `+` and the numbers `1` and `2`. Evaluating that will look up the function named by the symbol `+` and call it with arguments `1` and `2`.

`(list + '1 '2)` produces a list of the function named by the symbol `+` and the numbers `1` and `2`. Evaluating that will call the function that's already directly an element of the list with the arguments from the rest of the list.

There's never a need to quote numbers, by the way. They're self-evaluating.

**EDIT**:

The more interesting case which you didn't address in your headline is what happens in the `(eval '('+ 1 2))` case? Why does this not return `3` like the other cases that all end up calling the function named by `+` with the arguments `1` and `2`?

The answer is that it's  different because this time, you have quoted the symbol `+` twice. Because of that, the symbol doesn't get resolved to the function it names, instead the symbol itself is called as a function.

Now what is the behaviour when a symbol gets called as a function? It treats its first argument as a map and looks itself up as a key in that map. But the number `1` is obviously not a map, so it would now usually return `nil` to indicate that no matching key was found.

In this case though, there's a second argument to the call to the symbol `+`, and that second argument gets used as the default value to return when no matching key was found. So that's why the form `(eval '('+ 1 2))` returns `2`.

**EDIT 2**:

OK, and now to finally answer the question: why does quoting a list produce different results than calling the `list` function with the same arguments. That's because a quote `'` stops all evaluation on the list it's used on, but the `list` function evaluates its arguments before producing a list with them as elements.

These differences all becomes very clear when you print the various forms instead of sending them directly to `eval`:

```
user> '(+ 1 2)
(+ 1 2)
user> '('+ 1 2)
((quote +) 1 2)
user> (list '+ '1 '2)
(+ 1 2)
user> (list + '1 '2)
(#<core$_PLUS_ clojure.core$_PLUS_@165c64> 1 2)
```

You see that the first and third case produce a result that prints the same, because in both these cases you've quoted `+` once. In the second case, `+` is quoted twice instead, and in the last it isn't quoted at all.

**EDIT 3**:

One last addition that should hopefully clarify things even further: unless its first element names a macro or special operator, `eval` will recursively evaluate all elements of a list (including the first) before evaluating the list itself by calling its (evaluated) first argument as a function with the rest of the list as arguments.

If that first element is `'+` or `(quote +)` (these are two different ways to write the same thing, the quoted symbol `+`), it will evaluate to the symbol `+` and that will be called as function.

If the first element is `+`, that will evaluate to the the actual addition function (`clojure.core$_PLUS_`). If it already is that function, it will stay the same (basically all types besides lists and symbols are self-evaluating). In both cases, `eval` will then call that function.